# PHP Simple HTML DOM - Top level elements only

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I have searched through some other threads here but have not found the perfect solution

if I have the following layout

```
    <html>
<div>   <---- This one
      <div> text </div>
      <div> text </div>
</div> 
<p> text </p>
 <div>  <---- This one
      <div> text </div>
      <div> text </div>
</div>  
<p> text </p>
</html>
```

How would I go about getting only the divs on the top level. (NOTE: the two divs inside is only an exmaple, there could be just  one, or could be 5 or 6.

Note: The rest of the code that this ties into is using the Simple html dom, I need this to work with that.

Comment: With CSS selectors / jQuery?

Comment: Show an example of the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you doing this server side with PHP when it would be much easier to do it with jQuery/CSS Client Side?

Comment: @PeeHaa Fair point, although I would not see *many* benefits of this due to the complex code needed server side. +1 for your posted answer anyway :-)

Comment: This needs to be server side, its part of a much larger code and program.  However this is just an offset of something im working on.

Comment: @Ryan I have no code as I dont know how to grab top level elements only. so there is nowhere to start.

One solution though I was thinking was grabbing all children in "html" and then checking if they are a div.. but this has proven trickey

Answer (score 2):

One possibiltity is to use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). It will look something like the following:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// one of the few cases where you may use error suppression
@$doc->loadHTML($yourHtml);

$xPath = new XPath($doc);
$nodes = $xPath->query('//html/div');
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, but it should at least get you close*